# Оптимизировать python задачу на двумерные массивы

Tags: python, list

Помогите ускорить решение, пожалуйста!

Условие: в первой строке вводится число N, далее в N строках вводится по 2 числа a и b. Их нужно считать, если b не равен 0, то список [a, b] добавляется в массив. Соответственно, если в течение ввода b не равен 0, то получаем двумерный массив array[N][2]. Задача в том, чтобы отсортировать наш массив array сначала по убыванию второго элемента, потом по возрастанию первого элемента. Затем выводим текущее количество вложенных списков (необязательно N, т.к. по ходу ввода b  могло быть равно 0). И, наконец, выводим отсортированный массив.

```
n = int(input())
all = []
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    if b != 0:
        all.append([a, b])
all.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
print(len(all))
for i in all:
    print(*i)
```

Проблема в том, что решение не проходит по времени. Есть ли какой-то способ ускорить код?

Comment: У вас же недавно другой вопрос был. Удалили? Ну тогда и здесь нет смысла что-то отвечать.

Comment: @MBo Верно, вопрос удалил, потому что проблема оказалась не в коде и была устранена самостоятельно. Не знал, что удалять вопросы - моветон. На будущее запомню.

Comment: @MBo Тем не менее, сейчас правда нужна помощь, если вам не сложно, я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Криминала в удалении нет, тем более что ответа не успели получить. Однако удалять имеет смысл плохие вопросы, а ваш хороший, с описанием проблемы, с правильными идеями решения и кодом. С точки зрения "наполнения вселенской базы знаний" как-то неправильно, что человек получает подсказку или сам находит решение, и уничтожает все следы.

Comment: Про данный вопрос - если нет дополнительных условий (вдруг у вас a целые в диапазоне 0..9, например), то трудно что-то ещё предположить. Разве что сразу список максимальной длины завести, чтобы не было перераспределений памяти.